# Uploading File of Maximum size or greater than default size set on php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I need to upload the larger file, I am using Laravel.
Scenario 1: When I was tried the first time then it was only uploading less than 5MB, for that, I have changed setting in php.ini file like `upload_max_filesize = 50M` and `post_max_size = 500M` , Now larger size file is uploading as per specified size. But the problem is for scenario 2:

Scenario 2: The same code and same php.ini behavior when I am using on my Amazon EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04 (using the LAMP), I am not able to upload the file more than 2-3 MB, I have verified my php.ini, where `upload_max_filesize is 50M` and `post_max_size is 50`, I am not able to figure out the situation that why it is happening on Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: you can check your instance actual creds by dd(phpinfo()); and the location of your ini file too

Comment: I found there was another php.ini folder inside apache2 folder , I have modified there , then it works fine..Thanks for the comment...

Comment: i'll put this as answer mark it write for others help

Answer (score 0):

you can check your instance actual creds by `dd(phpinfo());` and the location of your ini file too
there might be another ini file exists in your server
hope it will help